# Are void * pointers meant for generic typing in C?

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion, void

I often see void pointers being cast back and forth with other types of pointers and wonder why, I see that malloc() returns a void pointer that needs to be cast before used also.

I am very new to C and come from Python so pointers are a very new concept to wrap my head around.

Is the purpose of the void * pointer to offer some "dynamic" typing?

Take this code as example, is it valid code?

```
struct GenericStruct{
    void *ptr;
};

// use void pointer to store an arbitrary type?
void store(struct GenericStruct *strct, int *myarr){
    strct->ptr = (void *) myarr;
}

// use void pointer to load an arbitrary type as int*?
int *load(struct GenericStruct *strct){
    return (int *) strct->ptr;
}
```

Comment: There are no dynamic types in C. A type descibes a the size of required memory and the behaviour of some built-ins like +/- etc.. The size of a pointer does not depend on the type it is pointing to though, but on your OS. Try to understand pointer arithmetic next, maybe that can help you understand pointers better.

Aside from that @Vlad from Moscows answer answers your question very succintly.

Comment: Casting a pointer returned by `malloc` is not required. And you also should not do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of a `void *` is to provide a welcome exception to some of C's typing rules.  With the exception of `void *`, you cannot assign a pointer value of one type to an object of a different pointer type without a cast - for example, you cannot write

```
int p = 10;
double *q = &p; // BZZT - cannot assign an int * value to a double *
```

When assigning to pointers of different types, you have to explicitly cast to the target type:

```
int p = 10;
double *q = (double *) &p; // convert the pointer to p to the right type before assigning to q
```

*except* for a `void *`:

```
int p = 10;
void *q = &p; // no cast required here.
```

In the old days of K&R C, `char *` was used as a "generic" pointer type<sup>1</sup> - the memory allocation functions `malloc/calloc/realloc` all returned `char *`, the callback functions for `qsort` and `bsearch` took `char *` arguments, etc., but because you couldn't directly assign different pointer types, you had to add an explicit cast (if the target wasn't a `char *`, anyway):

```
int *mem = (int *) malloc( N * sizeof *mem );
```

Using explicit casts everywhere was a bit painful.

The 1989/1990 standard (C89/C90) introduced the `void` data type - it's a data type that cannot store any values.  An expression of type `void` is evaluated only for its side effects (if any)<sup>2</sup>.  A special rule was created for the `void *` type such that a value of that type can be assigned to/from any other pointer type without need of an explicit cast, which made it the new "generic" pointer type.  `malloc/calloc/realloc` were all changed to return `void *`, `qsort` and `bsearch` callbacks now take `void *` arguments instead of `char *`, and now things are a bit cleaner:

```
int *mem = malloc( sizeof *mem * N );
```

You cannot dereference a `void *` - in our example above, where `q` has type `void *`, we cannot get at the value of `p` without a cast:

```
printf( "p = %d\n", *(int *)q );
```

Note that C++ is different in this regard - C++ does not treat `void *` specially, and requires an explicit cast to assign to different pointer types.  That's because C++ provides overloading mechanisms that C doesn't.

---

1. Every object type *should* be mappable to an array of `char`.

   In K&R C, all functions had to return a value - if you didn't explicitly type the function, the compiler assumed it returned `int`.  This made it difficult to determine which functions were actually *meant* to return a value vs. functions that only had side effects.  The `void` type was handy for typing functions that weren't meant to return a value.

Answer (score 2):

C suffers from the absence of function overloading. So most C "generic" functions as for example `qsort` or `bsearch` use pointers to `void *` that to be able to deal with objects of different types.

In C you need not to cast a pointer of any type to a pointer of the type `void *`.  And a pointer of any type can be assigned with a pointer of the type `void *` without casting.

So in C the functions from your code snippet can be rewritten like

```
void store(struct GenericStruct *strct, int *myarr){
    strct->ptr = myarr;
}

int *load(struct GenericStruct *strct){
    return strct->ptr;
}
```

Comment: Oh, right, I thought the conversion were necessary.

Comment: @Jeacom A conversion from a pointer of the type void * to a pointer of any other type is needed in C++.

Comment: @Jeacom The pointer *is* converted, but as mentioned in the answer, no cast is needed - the pointer is converted automatically. (The rules for C++ are different as mentioned by @Vlad.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is the purpose of the `void *` pointer to offer some "dynamic" typing?

No, because C has no dynamic typing.  But your title is about right, on the other hand -- `void *` serves roughly as a *generic* pointer type, in the sense that a pointer of that type can point to an object of any type.  But there is no dynamism as that term is usually applied in this sort of context, because values of type `void *` do not contain any information about the type of object to which they point.

The use, then, is for pointers where the type of the object pointed to does not matter (for a given purpose).  In some cases the *size* of the pointed-to object does matter, however, so that is sometimes provided alongside such pointers.  The standard [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function is a canonical example.  In other cases, such as generic linked lists, it is up to the user to know, somehow, what type of object is pointed to.

As @Vlad already observed, however, casting between `void *` and other object pointer types is not required in C.  Such conversions are performed automatically upon assignment, and in other contexts that use the same rules as assignment.